# How can we solve this Yacc conflict

Tags: conflict, yacc, reduce

```
%token A B C D E F G H
%%
x : y H y | z H z
;

y : G | t |  y B G | y B t
;

z : w | z D w
;

w : C | t | E z F
;

t : A
;
```

There is a reduce/reduce conflict because of t. How can we solve it?

Comment: Not sure why it was voted down so much - looks like pretty reasonably sized sample with descriptin of problem and question... Reasoning behind grammar maybe useful but not required...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  Unfortunately I think a lot of people just automatically down vote if they don't understand something / looks like spam.  I have no idea about Yacc, so can't help answer I'm afraid, however the question seems to be a reasonable one.

Comment: Yacc is a parser generator and i am designing a grammar. I simplified the problematic part of my grammar with letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the conflict between y: t and w: t is resolved in favor of y: t. If you want it the other way, reorder the corresponding rules. Or you can expand one of them like this :-

```
%token A B C D E F G H
%%
x : y H y | z H z
;

w : C | A | E z F
;

z : w | z D w
;

y : G |  A B G | A B A | y B G | y B A
;
```

Note that I've got rid of the t rule and removed the y: A rule by expanding it :-

Step 1: Eliminate the t: A rule

```
%token A B C D E F G H
%%
x : y H y | z H z
;

y : G | A |  y B G | y B A
;

z : w | z D w
;

w : C | A | E z F
;
```

Step 2:

```
%token A B C D E F G H
%%
x : y H y | z H z
;

y : G | A |  A B G | A B A | y B G | y B A
;

z : w | z D w
;

w : C | A | E z F
;
```